# Is it possible to have a custom italic css property that is less slanted?

Tags: html, css

I am following a design that contains a slanted text.
I used `font-style:italic` but the result is too much.

I am finding a way to make a custom css to have class that will make the text a little less slanted than the default `italic` property.

See images below: (left = design; right = html/css)
[image: THE DESIGN]
[image: MY IMPLEMENTATION]

Is there a way? Is this possible to achieve (even using a different approach)?

Comment: You can try some italic font. Many font has many is less slanted the default one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try with CSS3 `skew()` property like this :

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3eyzm39z/1/)

```
h1
{ 
text-transform: uppercase; 
font-family: arial; 
transform: skew(-13deg);
-webkit-transform: skew(-13deg);
}
```

Comment: In my case I have a long text, it has been skewing the whole height.